# MATLAB: How to delete characters from 2x1 or nx1 string?

Tags: string, matlab, erase

Good day.

Here I have a 2x1 string:

```
A = ["CHAPTER 1. Random info in middle one, Random info still continues. 1";...
     "CHAPTER 2. Random info in middle two. Random info still continues. 1"];
```

How can I remove "CHAPTER #", and the last number and space at the back of the space? Here is my attempt:

```
%PlanA
for n=1:2
% Delete "Chapter+Nr"
A(n,1) = erase(A,'(CHAPTER \d)'); 
% Delete last nr 1 at end
A(n,1) = erase(A,'\d'); 
end

%PlanB
A(strcmp(A, 'CHAPTER \d')) = []
```

I have no idea why this is not working?

Help is appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: From the [`erase()` docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/erase.html): "`newStr = erase(str,match)` deletes all occurrences of `match` in `str`." _"no idea why this is not working?_" Because there are no occurrences of `'Chapter \d'` in any of your strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [regexprep](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) for this:

```
regexprep(A,'CHAPTER \d+\. (.+) \d$','$1')
ans = 

2×1 string array

"Random info in middle one, Random info still continues."
"Random info in middle two. Random info still continues."
```